# Creating "holes" in a binary H.264 bitstream

Tags: h.264, bitstream

I am trying to simulate data loss in a video by selectively removing H.264 bitstream data. The data is simply a raw H.264 file, which is essentially a binary file. My plan is to delete 2 bytes for every 100 bytes so as to achieve a 2% loss. Eventually, I will be testing the effectiveness of some motion vector error concealment algorithms.

It would be nice to be able to do this in a Unix environment. So far, I have investigated the command xxd for a bit and I am able to save a specific portion of a hex dump from a binary file. For example, to skip the first 50 bytes of a binary bitstream and save the subsequent 100 bytes, I would do the following:

`xxd -s 50 -l 100 inputBinaryFile | xxd -r > outputBinaryFile`

I'm hoping to incorporate something similar into a bash script that will automatically delete the last 2 bytes per 100 bytes. Furthermore, I would like the script to skip everything before the second occurrence of the sequence `00 00 01 06 05` (first P-frame SEI start code).

I don't know how much easier this could be in a C-based language but my programming skills are quite limited and I would rather deal with just Linux programming for now if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like an unusual loss model.

In an MPEG transport stream, you're likely to lose entire transport packets (188 bytes of 4header+184 payload).  The other formats I can think of don't go over lossy pipes.

Comment: Hi Mutant Bob. You are correct. The loss model described here is not very useful or practical. In fact, I have resorted to deleting whole slices in H.264 bitstreams as this is a much more realistic representation of data loss in packet-based wireless networks (802.11 in particular).